Weird Scrolling Behavior on mobile web
I have created a page where I have different section with different height. each section will appear and disappear with slide in and slide out. when they does not appear, they are hidden. on pc web browser, everything went smoothly until we actually try to view it in mobile phone. on the mobile phone, the scroll will always stuck near the top and will need to release then before scrolling again to reach the top. this is also true for the bottom.
we tried to create new project, which initially worked, but it happens again soon after

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Multi-Page Slider</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <style>
      .slide {
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="font-sans bg-gray-100">
    <!-- Container for the entire page -->
    <div id="container" class="relative h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <!-- 1st Page - Initial View -->
      <div
        id="page1"
        class="slide absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center bg-gradient-to-t from-blue-600 to-transparent p-4"
      >
        <div class="text-center text-white">
          <div class="mb-8">
            <img
              src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"
              alt="Heading Image"
              class="mx-auto"
            />
          </div>
          <button
            onclick="goToPage2()"
            class="px-6 py-3 bg-yellow-500 text-lg font-semibold rounded-full shadow-lg"
          >
            Start
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 2nd Page - Question Page -->
      <div
        id="page2"
        class="slide absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-start items-center bg-white text-center p-6 transform -translate-x-full overflow-y-auto"
      >
        <div class="mb-6">
          <p class="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">What is your favorite color?</p>
          <div class="space-y-4">
            <label class="block">
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red" class="mr-2" /> Red
            </label>
            <label class="block">
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue" class="mr-2" /> Blue
            </label>
            <label class="block">
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green" class="mr-2" />
              Green
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          onclick="goToPage3()"
          class="px-6 py-3 bg-green-500 text-lg font-semibold rounded-full shadow-lg"
        >
          Next
        </button>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="py-10">
          <h1 class="text-4xl py-10">AWESOME TEXT</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Additional long content -->
      </div>

      <!-- 3rd Page - Form Page -->
      <div
        id="page3"
        class="slide absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-gray-200 p-8 transform -translate-x-full"
      >
        <form id="form" class="w-full max-w-md">
          <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="name" class="block text-lg">Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              class="w-full p-3 border rounded"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="email" class="block text-lg">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              class="w-full p-3 border rounded"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="phone" class="block text-lg">Phone</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="phone"
              class="w-full p-3 border rounded"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="px-6 py-3 bg-blue-500 text-lg font-semibold rounded-full shadow-lg w-full"
            >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- 4th Page - Thank You Page -->
      <div
        id="page4"
        class="slide absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center bg-green-500 text-white text-center transform -translate-x-full"
      >
        <div>
          <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">Thank You!</h1>
          <p class="text-xl">We have received your submission.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
      function goToPage2() {
        document
          .getElementById("page1")
          .classList.add("transform", "-translate-x-full");
        document
          .getElementById("page2")
          .classList.remove("transform", "-translate-x-full");
      }

      function goToPage3() {
        document
          .getElementById("page2")
          .classList.add("transform", "-translate-x-full");
        document
          .getElementById("page3")
          .classList.remove("transform", "-translate-x-full");
      }

      document
        .getElementById("form")
        .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          document
            .getElementById("page3")
            .classList.add("transform", "-translate-x-full");
          document
            .getElementById("page4")
            .classList.remove("transform", "-translate-x-full");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

